# How to create total from the same value on different Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to have the sum of some values on different spreadsheet on one "total" spreadsheet.
Usually I start myself to find a solution and then ask for some help, but here, I have just no idea how I can do such a things.
I have created a "manual total" on a sheet, just to explain what I want.
I have a sheet by month
then I have a total sheet

And I would like this sheet to work automatically, month after month...

Comment: Now that I have edit and correct the question, anyway for somebody to delete the -1 evaluation on it, because it still there, and I found it really unfair !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,reduce(wraprows(,3,),tocol(E:E,1),lambda(a,c,let(Δ,{a;{indirect("'"&c&"'!A5:b25"),byrow(indirect("'"&c&"'!c5:ar25"),lambda(Σ,sum(Σ)))}},filter(Δ,index(Δ,,1)<>"")))),
     Γ,query(Σ,"Select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3) ''"),
     Ξ,unique(index(Γ,,2)),
     Δ,reduce(wraprows("skip_",3,),sequence(counta(Ξ)),lambda(a,c,{a;sort(filter(Γ,index(Γ,,2)=index(Ξ,c)),3,0);{"",index(Ξ,c),sum(filter(index(Γ,,3),index(Γ,,2)=index(Ξ,c)))}})),
     filter(Δ,index(Δ,,1)<>"skip_"))
```

- all the `months tab names` need be listed in ***Column_E*** (as in screenshot)
- some of the month tabs have column(s) until ***Column_AK*** & some of them till ***Column_AR***. Have them all consistently until `_AR` for the formula to work w/out error code.

[image]

***updated formula for fixes***:

```
=let(Σ,reduce(wraprows(,3,),tocol('LEGENDE PROJET'!I2:I,1),lambda(a,c,{a;{indirect("'"&c&"'!A5:b25"),byrow(indirect("'"&c&"'!c5:ar25"),lambda(Σ,SUM(Σ)))}})),
     Γ,query(Σ,"Select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3) ''"),
     Ξ,unique(index(Γ,,2)),
     Δ,reduce(wraprows("skip_",3,),sequence(COUNTA(Ξ)),lambda(a,c,{a;sort(filter(Γ,index(Γ,,2)=index(Ξ,c)),3,0);{"",index(Ξ,c),SUM(filter(index(Γ,,3),index(Γ,,2)=index(Ξ,c)))}})),
     filter(Δ,index(Δ,,1)<>"skip_"))
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/EOG3Opq.png Use the conditional formatting as shown in the screenshot to just highlight the `Total` rows `=($A1="")*len($B1)`

Comment: I know that I'am asking a lot, but I have encounter 2 situations that make the total fail

1/ if the first month is totally empty the total fail 2/ if a month is empty, the total from the following month will be double...

here in my spreadsheet, January and March are empty. If you fill January, it works, but the total from april double... here is the sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHbxIQoR8Fd1NfE1CSSH79w_FM24gnfglH-yTD4O1FM/edit#gid=1222163394

thanks for your help !

Comment: You kinda entered `April` month twice in the months list; so the double number and try the updated formula in the answer above to fix the `scenario 1`